# Autohotkey: How to construct dynamic parameters to call a function

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to Use Win+Alt+<arrow-keys> to move current active window around. So I come up with Autohotkey script:

```
WinMoveRelative(rx, ry)
{
    ; Move current window by a relative rx, ry value. rx, ry can be positive or negative
    WinGetPos, x, y, width, height, A
    absx := x + rx
    absy := y + ry
    WinMove, A, , %absx%, %absy%
}
;
g_moveunit := 20
!#Left::  WinMoveRelative(0-%g_moveunit%, 0)  ; DON'T WORK
!#Right:: WinMoveRelative(%g_moveunit%, 0)    ; DON'T WORK
!#Up::    WinMoveRelative(0, -20)     ; works
!#Down::  WinMoveRelative(0, 20)      ; works
```

I just can't figure out how to pass `g_moveunit` and its negative value to the function. Please help.

Autohotkey v1.1.13.01

Comment: Don't enclose g_moveunit in percent signs (`%`); it's an expression! Rule of thumb: When working with pure numbers or passing something to a function, it's an expression.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Please write it as answer. And I find that ``g_moveunit:=20`` has to appear before any hotkey definition, otherwise, `g_moveunit` will always be empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enclose g_moveunit in percent signs (`%`); it's an expression. Rule of thumb: When working with pure numbers or passing something to a function, it's an expression.

*[Side note]* To your other problem described in your comment:
Read the [FAQ](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#autoexec), respectively the explanation of the **auto-execute section**.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm feeling lucking to get this answer with merely 8 views during two whole days.

Comment: @JimmChen The AHK docs/FAQs are a great place to find answers. Try reading there next time and you may not have to sweat it out here ;)